# Polygon Clipping using Vatti's Algorithm explained

Tags: algorithm, polygon, clipping

After having read this paper by Vatti about his algorithm (https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/129902.129906), I still don't get how exactly it works.

Could anyone please help me understand how Vatti's Algorithm actually works?

Here are two Triangles I just made up:

[image]

S: [[5, 1], [8, 1.5], [6, 7]]

C: [[1, 5], [12, 6], [6, 10]]

Comment: After almost 1 year, did you find out?

Comment: No, not really. I have a rough idea, but there are still parts I don't understand yet.